# Is it correct to say "The mug's wobbly if you do like that"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

There is a small stone on a flat surface like a table and Tom puts his mug on it as shown in the picture.

Is it correct to say "**The mug's wobbly if you do like that**"?

Comment: To me, it would be more idiomatic to say "Don't set your cup on that stone. It'll wobble or tip over."

Comment: "The mug will be unstable if you set it there."

Comment: "Do like that," certainly is not proper.

Comment: I don't get the "do like that" part, am I missing something?

Comment: **The mug will be wobbly if you do that** - but _if you put it there_ would be more idiomatic..

Comment: …if you do [what?] like that…. Use the pronoun "it" after the verb *do* or use a different verb for instance *place it there* OR *put it there* OR *rest your mug on top of that* (not as idiomatic as the others but it's grammatical)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"if you do **it** like that" would be fine - "like that" refers to the way something is being done, it implies that there are different options, and Tom's chosen to do "it" (the act of putting a cup down) in a bad way. "Don't do it in that way, do it like this".

"If you do that" just refers to the action - the thing you're doing will have this effect. So don't do that thing!